# Android Studio How to change App name(@toolbar) for each activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I realize for every activity i have, it shows the Apps name. How to change the name at the toolbar for other activity?

Comment: that's why I am giving instruction you to use `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a label attribute in every activity in the android manifest `label` that can be used to set the name in the toolbar.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  <------ Activity Name
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

</activity>
```

Or you can change it programatically through:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ACTIVITY NAME");
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
getActionBar().setTitle("YOUR TITLE");   
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("YOUR TITLE");  // provide compatibility to all the versions
```

to `onCreate()` for your needed Activities.

> By xml

In your `manifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name=".YOURActivity"
        android:label="@string/YOUR_TITLE"
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can provide title to all your Activities in the `Manifest`

```
<activity
  android:name=".Contents.HomeActivty"
  android:label="TITLE" />
```

OR
 You can setTitle programmatically using `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TITLE");`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Title and subtitle
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.about_toolbar_title);
    toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.themeToolbarColor));
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different names you can change them in the strings.xml file. You can change the existing variable

```
<string name="app_name">YourAppName</string>
```

by replacing the 'YourAppName' to whatever you want.

Also, you can add new variables for other names!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar            
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

> In Java

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
      if(toolbar != null) {
          setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
          getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My custom toolbar!");

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change whole app name then

```
<string name="app_name">YourAppName</string>
```

But if you want to change particular activity title then

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

</activity>
```

Or you can change it form .java programmatically through:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ACTIVITY NAME");
```